# Getting Bubble sort to work in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

```
else if (selection == 16)
{
    int bubbleCount = 0;
    for(bubbleCount = 0; bubbleCount < arraySize; bubbleCount++)
    {
        if (theArray[bubbleCount] > theArray[bubbleCount+1])
        {
            swap(theArray[bubbleCount], theArray[bubbleCount+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

For clarification of what's going on here:

- `selection` is my variable for choosing what's getting done in my program. In this particular instance the bubble sort selection is `16`.
- `arraySize` is the user specified size of the array.
- `bubbleCount` is just an arbitrary name for the typical for loop arrays use.

I thought my logic was fine. What should happen is the array starts at my count and compares it to the adjacent element in the array. If it's larger, they swap. The for loop should execute for `arraySize` iterations. When I tested this with an array of randomly generated numbers, it failed to fully sort. Where did I mess up?

Comment: What was the input, the expected outcome and the actual result?

Comment: You need two loops for a proper bubble sort, not one.

Comment: Mark's right - go read about bubble sorts.  Further, you're comparing the element at index bubbleCount with the following one, so your for loop should stop when bubbleCount < arraySize - 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code snippet the following way

```
// enum { BubbleSort = 16, /*...*/ }

else if ( selection == BubbleSort )
{
    for( int last = arraySize; last > 1 ; --last )
    {
        for ( int first = 1; first < last; ++first )
        {
            if ( theArray[first] < theArray[first - 1] )
            {
                swap( theArray[first], theArray[first - 1] );
            }
        }
    }
}
```